# How to add audio to video using ffmpeg on Linux?

Tags: linux, audio, video, ffmpeg

I am able to do this just fine on Mac and Windows, but seem to be getting an error on Linux:

```
Command Failed: ffmpeg -y -loglevel warning -hide_banner -nostats -strict -2 -i "/home/runner/work/stone/stone/build/mount.quiet.mp4" -i "/home/runner/work/stone/stone/build/crow.wav" -shortest -c:v copy -c:a aac "/home/runner/work/stone/stone/build/mount.crow.mp4"
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #1.0 : stereo
[aac @ 0xdfa9a0] The encoder 'aac' is experimental but experimental codecs are not enabled, add '-strict -2' if you want to use it.
```

What encoder should I use instead to get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ffmpeg` must be very old to need `-strict` for AAC encoding. Unfortunately, `-hide_banner` is hiding the version and other info.

You have two ways to fix this:

- Option placement matters. You're using `-strict` as an input option. Move it so it's after the inputs so it is an output option.
- Update to a modern version and you won't need `-strict`. I recommend this solution. For Linux yo can download a static build from [johnvansickle.com](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) (see [FAQ](https://www.johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/faq/) for install instructions).

Comment: I am doing a fresh install of ffmpeg on GitHub Actions / CI using Ubuntu 16.04, so that should be a recent version right?

Comment: @LancePollard I don't know anything about GitHub Actions / CI but if you run `ffmpeg` and provide the first line I can verify.